# How to update SQL table column with a list of new values from a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

Is there a way to update a column in an SQL table with some new data using pandas? maybe with a list of values? Essentially what I would like to do is...

1. Connect to database
2. Grab a table from the database-> covert to DataFrame
3. Run a script to update the values of a column of that DataFrame
4. Update the database table with new values / new DataFrame

The tables I am working with are large (> 100,000 rows).

I can do steps 1, 2, & 3, but I don't know how to do step 4 and put the updated values back into the database table...

## example script

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc as odbc

sql_conn = odbc.connect(<connections tuff>)

query = "SELECT * FROM myTable"
df = pd.read_sql(query, sql_conn)

myNewValueList = [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,….]  # long list of new values to update with
df[newColumnValues] = myNewValueList 

sql = "UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = %s"
val = df[newColumnValues]

mycursor.execute(sql_conn , val)
```

Comment: You might want to check out  `pandas.to_sql` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc as odbc

# Connect to the database
sql_conn = odbc.connect(<connection_stuff>)

# Read the data
query = "SELECT * FROM myTable"
df = pd.read_sql(query, sql_conn)

# Update the DataFrame
myNewValueList = [11, 12, 13, 14, ...]  # Your new values
df['myColumn'] = myNewValueList

# Update statement
sql = "UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = ? WHERE <PrimaryKeyColumn> = ?"

# Update the database
cursor = sql_conn.cursor()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute(sql, (row['myColumn'], row['<PrimaryKeyColumn>']))

# Commit the changes and close the connection
sql_conn.commit()
cursor.close()
sql_conn.close()
```

In the above code snippet, replace `<connection_stuff>`, `<PrimaryKeyColumn>`, and `myColumn` with your actual connection details, primary key column, and column to be updated. The primary key is used to uniquely identify each row for the update.

This method executes an SQL update for each row, which might not be very efficient for large datasets. For more efficient bulk updates, you may want to consider pandas' `to_sql` method. It allows you to write the DataFrame to the SQL table directly, which can be faster and more straightforward than updating each row individually as in the above approach.

However, `to_sql` has its nuances. It is used for inserting new rows into a database, and handling updates requires considering the `if_exists` parameter. So, what you can do is write your modified DataFrame to a temporary table in your database, perform an update from the temporary table to the actual target table, and, finally, drop the temporary table. Following is an implementation using this approach:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc as odbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# Connect to the database using SQLAlchemy (needed for to_sql)
# Replace <connection_stuff> with your database details
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://<connection_stuff>')

# Existing code to modify the DataFrame
sql_conn = odbc.connect(<connection_stuff>)
query = "SELECT * FROM myTable"
df = pd.read_sql(query, sql_conn)
myNewValueList = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
df['newColumnValues'] = myNewValueList

# Write the modified DataFrame to a temporary table
temp_table_name = 'temp_myTable'
df.to_sql(temp_table_name, engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)

# Execute an SQL query to update the original table from the temporary table
with engine.connect() as conn:
    update_query = f"""
    UPDATE myTable
    SET myColumn = temp.newColumnValues
    FROM myTable
    INNER JOIN {temp_table_name} as temp
    ON myTable.id = temp.id  -- Assuming 'id' is the unique identifier
    """
    conn.execute(update_query)

    # Drop the temporary table
    conn.execute(f"DROP TABLE {temp_table_name}")
```

Please note that this method requires the creation of a temporary table, which might require permissions depending on your database setup.